# Why is this '=' syntax incorrect in this js snippet?

Tags: javascript

```
var hungry = true;
var foodHere = true;

var eat = function() {
  if (hungry && foodHere === true) {
      return(true);
  } else {
      return(false);
  }`

};
```

The first line is the correct syntax. For a long time I was just saying `hungry && foodHere = true`... and I couldn't figure out (and still don't understand) why that is wrong. I understand the difference between `=` (assignment) and `===` (equal to). I assigned the variables to be `true` initially, so aren't I asking in the if statement if that's what they're set to? Why am I setting the variables `=` to in the var definition, but then when checking them I'm using the `===` value?

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript

Comment: _“Why am I setting the variables = to in the var definition, but then when checking them I'm using the === value?”_ – because the first one is an assigment, and the second one a comparison …?

Comment: your `hungry && foodHere === true` syntax is wrong. it's not doing what you want it to do. It should be: `hungry === true && foodHere === true`.
if you want to assign 2 variables at the same time you would do `var hungry = true, foodHere = true`. You can't shorthand assign and you can't shorthand compare either.

Comment: Why does this question have 5 downvotes but no votes to close? The downvotes don't seem helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`=` is only used to assign variables. `===` or `==` are used to compare. For a good example, we must look into comparison operators.

## Syntax

The syntax of comparison operators is fairly simple, use them to evaluate expressions. The comparasin operators are:

```
=== //strict equality
==  //Parsed or partial equality
>   //Greater Than
<   //Less than
>=  //Greater than or equal to
<=  //Less than or equal to
```

To properly use these, you must know the proper syntax. For example, I can't do something like:

```
if(true == 1 === true) //do something
```

as that would invalidate the code, and slow it down by much using `==`, which brings me to my next section.

## Equality

The two equality operators in JavaScript are `==` and `===`. They do two very different things.

### ===

The strict equality (`===`) tests whether two values are exactly equivalent, both in type and value.

### ==

The Parsed equality (`==`) tests whether two values are equalivent in value, but parses to try and connect different types.

## Inequality

There are 2 main inequality value in JavaScript (`!==`) they are pretty self explainatory based on the equalities (`===`, and `==`)
here's a chart explaining the three.

```
          1      0      true      false      null      undefined     ""
        1 ===   !==       ==        !==        !==         !==      !==
        0 !==   ===      !==        ==         ==          ==       !==
     true  ==   !==      ===        !==        !==         !==      !==
    false !==   ==       !==        ===        ==          ==       ==
     null !==   ==       !==        ==         ==          ==       ==
undefined !==   ==       !==        ==         ==          ===      !==
      ""  !==   ==       !==        ==         ==          !==      ===
```

Adding onto what @jcollum said, `=` defines a variable value, and `if(something === true)` simplifies into `if(something)`. Similarly, `if(something === false)` simplifies into if`(!something)`.

You also need to do comparisons separately. `if(7 & 6 < 10)` returns false because it is the simplified version of `if(7 === true && 6 < 10)`.

Answer (score 1):

It turns:

`hungry && foodHere === true`

into

`hungry && true`

or just

`hungry`

Using the assignment operator instead of the comparison operator is stopping your logic from working correctly.